# Displaying random li's display's NULL

Tags: jquery, random, null

> How do I display a random set of list
>   items, I think I have this down.
>   Thanks!

//Count the number of li's in the object
            var listCount = $("li.contentBlock", obj).length;

```
        //Generate a random number from the count of li's
        var randomListNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * listCount -1);

        //Generate list of items based on the amount of li's that are present
        var firstList = "<li class='contentBlock'>"+$("li:eq("+randomListNumber+")", obj).html()+"</li>";

        //Target element that contains that list
        var place = $("ul", obj).html();

        //Combine ul container and list generate
        var newPlace = firstList+place;

        //Replace current ul and li with newly generated random list
        $("ul", obj).html(newPlace);
```

Comment: On the load of the page I am trying to randomly generate list items within a ul. obj is var for this content gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Save this as an .html file for an example

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var len = $("ul.contentBlock li").length;       

            $("ul.contentBlock li").each(function(){
                $(this).html(Math.floor(Math.random() * len));
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="contentBlock"> 
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```